# How to read and write file data using blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I am a beginner to Blockchain. Can you suggest me some ways on how to write a file data to blockchain and how to read data from a blockchain to a file. If this cannot be done in Ethereum then on which platform it can be done? Moreover it should happen in realtime. Amount of data is very less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SKALE (a sidechain) you can use https://skale.network/docs/developers/products/file-storage. Otherwise it will be expensive to store files on the Ethereum mainnet, but you can get an idea on how to do it from their implementation: https://github.com/skalenetwork/filestorage/blob/develop/contracts/FileStorage.sol.